# Link two databases through the java application

Tags: java

I have a java application that migrates data from one database to another.
I have to do update data in my database with data from another database. Another database provided by the customer.

Now it is this way:

I make a request from java application to my database(oracle) to get the address and driver of database, user, password from which I want to get the data.

```
oracleConn = DriverManager.getConnection(...); //connect to my DB

PreparedStatement prStServerP = this.oracleConn.prepareStatement("SELECT adress, driver, user, password from connections where svr_id = ?"); //settings to connect to the remote DB
```

Then I establish a connection with the remote database.

```
Connection dbConn = this.getDbConnection(svrId);
```

From my database I get "selects" for the remote Database.

```
oraclePrSt = this.oracleConn.prepareStatement("SELECT slq_select FROM SELECTS where svr_id...")
```

Also from my database I choose the table which will put the data from the remote database.

I Doing "selects" in a remote database and put the data:

```
Statement dbPrSt = dbConn.createStatement();
ResultSet dbRs = dbPrSt.executeQuery(oracleRs.getString(3)); //here selects that I got from my database
ResultSetMetaData dbRsMd = dbRs.getMetaData();
```

After all of this I record the results from a remote database into a file and using sqlLoader writes data in my database.

Please, tell me is there any options to make it easier or better?

Comment: If the two db are both *Oracle* I think there are tools that could help. Or, if those tools are does not fit your cases, you could look at *ETL* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load), as your problem is this kind, I think. Anyway, it is **off topic** here.

Comment: @MarioSantini My database is oracle, but the remote DB is different

Comment: Ok, that's why the *Oracle* tools are not useful. I think you have to have a round on the *ETL*s. This is the proper way. If you have some *EJB*s you could have a look on *Apache Camel*, not sure if could help on different db. But still **off topic**. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is fine if you only have a couple of tables to copy.
If you have a whole database you could export the entire database to a SQL dump and them run that whole script in the new database manually.

If you need to do transformation to the data, then you can look into [Oracle ETL tools](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/ettover.htm).